# Take voltage every 60 seconds C++ Sketch

Tags: c++

Can someone explain how to modify this program to "ReadAnalogVoltage" once every 60 seconds, forever.

Right now it reads the voltage every millisecond (I think), forever.

Too much information is being generated.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Rob.

```
    > /*
     ReadAnalogVoltage
     Reads an analog input on pin 0, converts it to voltage, and prints 
     the result to the serial monitor.
      Attach the center pin of a potentiometer to pin A0, and the outside 
     pins to +5V and ground.

     This example code is in the public domain.
   */

   // the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
   void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   }

   // the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
   void loop() {
    // read the input on analog pin 0:
    int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
    float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
    // print out the value you read:
    Serial.println(voltage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to lower the sampling rate. Place a counter inside your loop and only print when the counter reaches a certain value. Be sure to reset the value after printing.

```
int counter = 0;
void loop() {
    // read the input on analog pin 0:
    int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
    float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
    // print out the value you read:
    if(counter >= 1000000){
        Serial.println(voltage);
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

2. The best way to solve this is with an time [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt). The actual mechanics of setting the interrupt will depend on what hardware you are using.

Comment: Would inserting "delay(60000);" be a safe way of doing it too or are there negative side effects?